# Will this crankset fit my bottom bracket?

Tags: bottom-bracket, crankset

I've got a 2004 Trek 4300 that I need to replace the crankset on. I was able to look up the bottom bracket size [here](http://www.vintage-trek.com/Trek-Fisher-Klein-Lemond/2004specmanualTrek.pdf) and see that it's a 73x122.5.

I'd like to buy [this crankset](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002FB2YA6) but I'm not exactly sure how to know if it will fit or not? The specs say:

```
Square taper crank accepts 68x122.5 mm spindle
```

Does that mean it *will not* fit mine which has a shell size of 73?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will fit.

If you need references: If you look at the [Shimano Tech Doc](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Alivio-Acera/SI_0094A/SI-0094A-001-ENG_v1_m56577569830667768.PDF), it suggests the Shimano BB-UN26 (which you can find that you can fit it in that version).